# Put messages into Win Crash Dump; !dbgprint; DbgPrint; DbgPrintEx

Tags: windows, driver, device-driver, wdk, bsod

I'm 'debuging' BSOD caused by driver on Win10 machine.

I've tried to use `DbgPrint()` or `DbgPrintEx()` to put messages in crash dump so they could be accessed by analysing that dump in 'windbg.exe' by calling `!dbgprint`.

I'm getting nothing all the time.

```
0: kd> !dbgprint
DbgPrint buffer is empty.
```

Examples of dump messages for references:

```
DbgPrint("## %s : %u\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "## %s : %u\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
```

Please note that PC running the driver is different from development PC. I could not connect WinDbg to 'running' machine and watch it in real time. So I'm trying to get log before crash and get a values of some variables. Basically all I could count on is `MEMORY.DMP` file.

If there is other ways to archive same/similar logging, I'd appreciate advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if DbgPrint buffer is kept always, I think that You should use [WPP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-software-tracing) and [IFR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/using-wpp-recorder) (Inflight Trace Recorder) which always record your traces even with dump.

Comment: As I got WPP is not an option since it needs 'TraceLog' running on remove machine. IFR with a help of `TraceEvents(...)`, on the other hand, gives what I asked, log messages in Crash Dump. Thanks.